# does UIImage have an equivalent of myLabel.hidden = YES?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uilabel

I'd like to hide an UIImage with a code in a method ... then display something else in its place and then re-enable it again. How would I go about doing this ?

I know how to do this with UILabels (myLabel.hidden = YES) but not with UIImage

thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure that your `UIImage` is enclosed inside of a `UIImageView`:

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImageName.png"];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];

self.imageView = imgView; // assuming you have a property called imageView

[imgView release];

[self.view addSubview:self.imageView]; //in your view controller
```

once you've done this, you can use:

```
[self.imageView setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: @Rog, haha, I've been spending a littttle too much time on this site :)

Comment: works great! thank you both ... just one thing: you have a small typo in your code (missing : between imageName and @)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the same way to an UIImageView.

UIImages by themselves do not get added/displayed in a view.